# Angular orderby filter in ng repeat do not actually sort underlying data

Tags: angularjs

To clear up any misconceptions about the heading.. the items in a table do appear to be sorted when an orderby filter is used in the ng-repeat expression. However I noticed that the underlying data isn't being actually sorted at all.

There is a scenario where I actually need the data being displayed in the filter to be sorted as displayed in the table, for generating reports. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Sort the data in your controller?

Comment: I did have to implement it separately .. Like before generating the report I sorted and grouped the data according to the parameters selected. But then there were slight discrepancies. For example , while the orderby filter treats a '-' as the lowest number in an array of number as text, my sorting code would do the opposite. So, I want to avoid writing a separate sorting function

Comment: If filter modified the underlying data then it would be less useful. Sort the data yourself.